# EnumDisplaySettings determine failure

Tags: c++, winapi

How to determine winapi `EnumDisplaySettings` failure? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd162611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If the function fails, the return value is zero.

also

> Graphics mode indexes start at zero. To obtain information for all of
>   a display device's graphics modes, make a series of calls to
>   EnumDisplaySettings, as follows: Set iModeNum to zero for the first
>   call, and increment iModeNum by one for each subsequent call. Continue
>   calling the function until the return value is zero.

How to determine if returned zero is a failure sign or mode doesnt exist (`iModeNum` value too big)?

There's nothing told about `GetLastError`. It seems like this winapi doesnt set last error on failure.

Comment: "If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero." what makes you think returned zero might be an indication of success? Incrementing `iModeNum` you enumerate until return is zero (that is failure, no more success starting from this increment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical for GDI api calls, they don't set the GetLastError error code.  All you've got is the "it didn't work" return value.

Do note that you **must** start with iModeNum at 0.  If that returns FALSE then you can safely assume there's something drastically wrong with the device name argument.  Keep incrementing iModeNum until you get FALSE.